# How can I further simplify this $A$ + $\neg A B$?

Tags: logic

I know there's a rule to simplify this formula $A$ + $\neg A B$, but I am not seeing it. Can someone tell me the name and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that : $A + ¬AB$ is :

> $A \lor (\lnot A \land B)$

we have, by [Distributivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) :

> $(A \lor (\lnot A \land B)) \equiv ((A \lor \lnot A) \land (A \lor B)) \equiv (TRUE \land (A \lor B)) \equiv (A \lor B)$

by [Identity laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence) : $TRUE \land p \equiv p$.

---

If instead the formula is : $(A \lor \lnot A) \land B$, we have simply : $TRUE \land B \equiv B$.

Comment: Shouldn't $+$ be "xor"?